# Unable to load DLL 'vcruntime140_cor3.dll' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf

Our product has been working fine. But one day we found that the exception was shown when manually closing it after putting it aside for the about 1 days.

The exception stack trace was as the following:

```
  KERNELBASE.dll!_RaiseException@16()   Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
  [Managed to Native Transition]        Annotated Frame
  DirectWriteForwarder.dll!__scrt_uninitialize_type_info() Line 60  C++ Symbols loaded.
  DirectWriteForwarder.dll!_app_exit_callback() Line 707    C++ Symbols loaded.
  DirectWriteForwarder.dll!<CrtImplementationDetails>::LanguageSupport::DomainUnload(System::Object^ __formal, System::EventArgs^ __formal) Line 731    C++ Symbols loaded.
  DirectWriteForwarder.dll!<CrtImplementationDetails>::ModuleUninitializer::SingletonDomainUnload(System::Object^ source, System::EventArgs^ arguments={System::AppDomain^}) Line 283   C++ Symbols loaded.
  [Native to Managed Transition]        Annotated Frame
  System.Private.CoreLib.dll!7a11a7bc() Unknown Non-user code. Native debugger skipped loading symbols for managed module.
  [Managed to Native Transition]        Annotated Frame
  System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.AppContext.OnProcessExit() Line 77  C#  Symbols loaded.
  [Native to Managed Transition]        Annotated Frame
  System.Private.CoreLib.dll![Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, native debugger attempting to walk managed call stack]  Unknown No symbols loaded.
  kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()    Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
  ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()  Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
  ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()    Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
```

Our product doesn't consume vcruntime140_cor3.dll directly. It is depended by WPF.
(Please refer to https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/37).

The strange thing is why vcruntime140_cor3.dll was not available at that time.
Maybe it has been moved out of memory? If yes, then I think it should be a common issue that other WPF apps should have the same issue.

It was hard to be reproduced and no other users have met this issue. I tried on two machines to put it aside for the weekend, but the issue wasn't reproduced our product could be closed correctly.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: There are issue with using old versions of Net with Core.  These problems have been fixed in Net 4.7.2 and newer.  Use Net 4.7.2 or newer and target the Core 3.0 (or 3.1).  The link you are referencing is from 2018 which is probably using an older version of Net.  Always check the date of any issues.  Links with old dates may no longer be valid since the bug was fixed in newer version of Net/Core.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng. We are using the .net core 3.1 so it should be a very newer one.

Comment: The code is using Kernel32 which is only on windows machines and not on Mac, Linux, or Mobile devices.  Core should not be using Kernel32 methods and probably fixed in newer releases.   Make sure you are using latest version of Core3.1 and install the runtime on a deploy machine.  Latest version of Core3.1 has bugs so you still may have issues : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. Yes, I agreed with you that our product might have triggered the unknown bug of .net core 3.1 which hasn't been fixed.